# Extracting a location name from JSON

Tags: regex, quotes

Given this text

`{"coord":{"lon":0.55,"lat":51.39},"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":285.81,"pressure":1011,"humidity":62,"temp_min":284.45,"temp_max":287.15},"wind":{"speed":11.3,"deg":170},"rain":{"1h":2.03},"clouds":{"all":20},"dt":1451480087,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5094,"message":0.0039,"country":"GB","sunrise":1451462577,"sunset":1451491082},"id":2648657,"name":"Gillingham","cod":200}`

I am trying to extract just the name of the location (without the quotes), in this case Gillingham.

I'm not great at regex and tried searching for `\"name":\".*"` with no results.

Comment: Deserializing this JSON is not an option? To capture the key-value-pair use `"name":[\s]*"[^"]*"`. But note that this does not consider escaped quotes within the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think regex is your best choice. You are reading a JSON format file. So you are probably best off using your built-in libraries to read JSON into a data-structure and then reading the "name" attribute, in pseudocode:

```
city = deserializeJson(JSONdataFIle.read)["name"]
```

A quick trick instead is:

```
city = filter (in CITIES) JsonData.splitInWords
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://txt2re.com/
```

I am NOT going to say this is the BEST solution for you in this case, but it is one. It is a site I often use to extract text from text that has a consistent pattern to it. Using the site, I got the Java code below. If that isn't what you are looking for now, you should bookmark the site for later to have in your software development arsenal. For me, all I did was paste your text into the site, press show matches, left clicked on "word" for your city name, then pressed the Java tab. The code was then generated for me to copy and paste.
if you copy and paste this code and run it as a Java main class in the IDE of your choice, you will see that your City name results; however, this will only work if the formatting of what you are filtering is consistent. If you are dealing with gigs of data to parse through, Java isn't your most efficient language for text parsing. Languages like Perl are good for that. But, with high end computing power today, it depends on what you're looking for.

import java.util.regex.*;

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String txt="{\"coord\":{\"lon\":0.55,\"lat\":51.39},\"weather\":[{\"id\":501,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"moderate rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"}],\"base\":\"cmc stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":285.81,\"pressure\":1011,\"humidity\":62,\"temp_min\":284.45,\"temp_max\":287.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":11.3,\"deg\":170},\"rain\":{\"1h\":2.03},\"clouds\":{\"all\":20},\"dt\":1451480087,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":5094,\"message\":0.0039,\"country\":\"GB\",\"sunrise\":1451462577,\"sunset\":1451491082},\"id\":2648657,\"name\":\"Gillingham\",\"cod\":200}";

    String re1=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re3=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re5=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re7=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re8="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   // Uninteresting: word
    String re9=".*?";   // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re10="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re11=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re12="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re13=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re14="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re15=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re16="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re17=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re18="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re19=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re20="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re21=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re22="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re23=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re24="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re25=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re26="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re27=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re28="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re29=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re30="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re31=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re32="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re33=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re34="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re35=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re36="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re37=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re38="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re39=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re40="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re41=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re42="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re43=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re44="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re45=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re46="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re47=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re48="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re49=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re50="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re51=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re52="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re53=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re54="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re55=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re56="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re57=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re58="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re59=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re60="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re61=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re62="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re63=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re64="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re65=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re66="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re67=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re68="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re69=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re70="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re71=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re72="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re73=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re74="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re75=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re76="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re77=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re78="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  // Uninteresting: word
    String re79=".*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
    String re80="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";    // Word 1

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12+re13+re14+re15+re16+re17+re18+re19+re20+re21+re22+re23+re24+re25+re26+re27+re28+re29+re30+re31+re32+re33+re34+re35+re36+re37+re38+re39+re40+re41+re42+re43+re44+re45+re46+re47+re48+re49+re50+re51+re52+re53+re54+re55+re56+re57+re58+re59+re60+re61+re62+re63+re64+re65+re66+re67+re68+re69+re70+re71+re72+re73+re74+re75+re76+re77+re78+re79+re80,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find())
    {
        String word1=m.group(1);
        System.out.print(word1.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('\"name":\".*?"', x)
```

I agree best approach is to read it as a JSON file.  I did, however try your regex code and after making the JSON a string file and this is what I got.

['"name":"Gillingham","cod"']

I made the match non-greedy '*?'  to make sure it just gets the name of the city

['"name":"Gillingham"']